# authentication fails with ldap in SVN subversion

Tags: apache, svn, httpd.conf

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module  modules/mod_dontdothat.so
LoadModule ldap_module        modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /mnt/repositories
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthType basic
   AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.0.0.1:389/DC=companyname,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" 
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=svn ldap,CN=Users,DC=companyname,DC=com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "pwd"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Authentication fails with password mismatch error whilst trying to login to svn repo.
Following is the config for `10-subversion.conf`

Tried everything for last 8 hours for nothing seemed to worked including changing the ports.
ldapsearch to the the ldap user works fine and returns the value.
checked firewall is not blocking the port 389.
checked selinux bits as well.

Tried adding the tha authz file in the config to provide specific users from AD access to repos, still doesn't work:

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/conf/access.conf
```

`access.conf` file has following config:

```
[repo:/]
user1 = rw
```

Comment: I see a close vote on this question not being about software development. Note that Subversion is a VCS *primarily used by software developers*. This question is perfectly on-topic. You wouldn't shoot down a Git question, would you?